# No inputevent produced on Android Chrome for a React controlled input

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome

I am getting this weird behavior. The weirdest part is that it's happening randomly. Here is a description of what happens :

I have a React App, with a controlled input, focus is done on this input when component is shown. Sometimes, on Android in Chrome (was not able to reproduce it in Firefox), when page is loaded keyboard opened (following the focus on the input) but when I type, nothing happens. Leaving/reopening the keyboard does not change a thing, but leaving the tab and coming back on it makes everything working.

I monitored events from devtools on document and it appears that when it's not working I only get these events :

1. `keydown` (KeyboardEvent)
2. `keyup` (KeyboardEvent)

While when it's working, I get these ones :

1. `keydown` (KeyboardEvent)
2. `input` (InputEvent)
3. `keyup` (KeyboardEvent)

So the input event is missing. Does anyone have an idea about what can lead to the input event not to be produced ??

I am hardly able to give a reproducible code since it's inside a massive project. But the input is rendered inside a React component with the following code :

```
<input
    value={this.props.query}
    onChange={this.onQueryChange}
    ref={focus}
    placeholder='Type your search here'
/>
```

Focus is focusing on the input on rendering (removing it does NOT remove the bug) :

```
const focus = input => {
    if (input) {
        const hasFocus = input === document.activeElement

        input.focus()

        if (!hasFocus) {
            input.select()
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue is welcome... Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your component code with event listener?

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself where the problem is coming from. I am posting the answer if it can help someone else...

This problem comes from a bug in Chrome (< 61 it seems), that occurred when there is a basic-auth in front of the website. More information about this bug can be found here : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740652

I was not able to reproduce the bug locally (I do not have basic-auth enable locally), but once I enabled it, the bug appeared.

Since I have basic-auth only in my staging env, I do not need to find a workaround for this. But there are some clues described in the bug ticket if needed...